# If else check for ujs file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I am building an Rails 4.1 webapp and I am using a an ajax form (remote true)
and a create.js.erb file with this content:

```
$("div.box-content").prepend('<%=j render @comment %>');
$(".empty-message").hide();
$(".textfield").val("");
```

How can I check if @comment is empty?
Right now it´s adding an empty row when there is no content (I don't want to add a row if comment is not set).

**Update**

```
def create
  @comment = @object.comments.create(comments_params)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either check server-side (conditionally output different JavaScript) or you can check in client-side in JavaScript.

Checking server-side involves testing whether `@comment` is set, and simply not output any of the prepending JavaScript:

```
<% if @comment.present? %>
  $("div.box-content").prepend('<%=j render @comment %>');
<% end %>
$(".empty-message").hide();
$(".textfield").val("");
```

Checking client-side involves outputting the empty value in a variable so you can inspect it in JavaScript vefore prepending it to your element:

```
var comment = '<%= j render @comment %>';
if (comment) {
  $("div.box-content").prepend(comment);
}
$(".empty-message").hide();
$(".textfield").val("");
```

I would use the first approach.

Comment: Unfortunately none of them work. The row is still added even if comment is blank.

Comment: Then you need to figure out what value is actually in `@comment`, and test for it. You didn't provide this, so I couldn't really help further.

Comment: Updated with create method from controller

Comment: Ok. Solved it. Used .valid? instead of .present? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, that was the missing piece. If you're using `Model.create`, there will always be a value, it will never be "empty" as you said. Empty in Ruby implies `nil`, or at the very least an empty array, both of which will return false for `present?`.